# What's the closest equivalent to tomboy notes on Mac OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard, tomboy

This was the most useful program I had under Ubuntu and I miss it greatly; evernote is bloated and complicated. Is there something like tomboy for the mac? Bonus points for iphone sync.

Comment: [Screenshots at Tomboy's features page](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/features.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [Tomboy Notes](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/?pagewanted=all) until you find an alternative.

> Tomboy is a desktop note-taking application for Linux, Unix, Windows, *and Mac OS X*.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

[How to install on OS X](http://live.gnome.org/Tomboy/Installing/Mac).

---

There are tons of simple note-taking applications on OS X. A popular iOS variant is [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/). Its website lists well known, sync-able Windows and Mac OS X applications. I suggest you try [JustNotes](http://selfcoded.com/app/justnotes/) and [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/) first.

Comment: Digging past broken links, I found http://selfcoded.com/justnotes2/ --YMMV.